# How to conditionally extract a Json value using JayWay JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "A":{
      "C":{
         "date":"2022-01-23"
      }
   },
   "B":{
      "D":{
         "date":"2022-01-24"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to extract the value `$.A.C.date` if it is not `null`, else I would like to extract `$.B.D.date`.

Basically I would like to write an `if else` expression using `JsonPath`.
However, I don't manage to make it work.

This is what I've tried:

```
String expression = "$.[?($.[?(@.A.C.date != null)].date || $.[?(@.B.D.date != null)].date)]";
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile(expression);
String json = "...my JSON...";
Object extractedValue = jsonPath.read(json);
System.out.println(extractedValue);
```

... but the output I get is simply an empty array: `[]`.

I have also tried this:

```
"$.[?($.[?(@.A.C.date != null)].A.C.date || $.[?(@.B.D.date != null)].B.D.date)]"
```

... but the output is a list with all the elements (because conditions match in both cases), yet I thought that writing `.A.C.date` was extracting just the `date` and not everything:

```
[
    {"A":{"C":{"date":"2022-01-23"}},
    "B":{"D":{"date":"2022-01-24"}}}
]
```

Anyone has an idea? I can't find anything online which is similar to this.

This is the dependency I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: _Basically I would like to write an if else expression using JsonPath._  ---> Why?  It would be so simpler to extract the two dates using JSONPath and then use pure java to do the if-else logic.

Comment: @AkshayG because I want this if/else logic to be injected by the configurators through the JsonPath and keep my code agnostic of what they actually want to extract :)

Comment: you cannot use if-else but you can use if and if not. Something like this. 

`$.concat($.[?(@.A.C.date != null)].C.date,$.[?(@.A.C.date == null)].B.D.date)`

Comment: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ site is down and I didn't find any other site to test jayway jsonpath online. It would help if you can share the reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* to do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "   \"A\":{" +
    "      \"C\":{" +
    "         \"date\":\"2022-01-23\"" +
    "      }" +
    "   }," +
    "   \"B\":{" +
    "      \"D\":{" +
    "         \"date\":\"2022-01-24\"" +
    "      }" +
    "   }," +
    "   \"E\":{" +
    "      \"F\":{" +
    "         \"date\":null" +
    "      }" +
    "   }" +
    "}");
String date = josson.getString("coalesce(A.C.date, B.D.date)");
System.out.println(date);
date = josson.getString("coalesce(E.F.date, B.D.date)");
System.out.println(date);
date = josson.getString("*.*.date[isNotNull()]");
System.out.println(date);
date = josson.getString("*().date[isNotNull()]");
System.out.println(date);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("**.**.date[isNotNull()]*");
System.out.println(node.toString());
```

**Output**

```
2022-01-23
2022-01-24
2022-01-23
2022-01-23
["2022-01-23","2022-01-24"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use new libraries :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `com.jayway.jsonpath`

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.*.*[?(@.date != \"null\")].date");
        List<String> read = jsonPath.read("{\n" +
                "   \"A\":{\n" +
                "      \"C\":{\n" +
                "         \"date\":\"2022-01-23\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   \"B\":{\n" +
                "      \"D\":{\n" +
                "         \"date\":\"2022-01-24\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}");
        System.out.println(read.get(0));
    }
}
```

It gets all the non-null dates then prints the first.

Comment: Thank you but I really need an if/else logic, what you're doing here relies on the fact that I always look for a field "date" (wherever it is), but what I actually need is to have conditional expressions that may be entirely different